# Live updates missing on new navigation tag pages

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, web-sockets, new-nav

In the alpha version of the new navigation, there does not seem to be a live update on the tag pages anymore.

Example: [Filtered Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?show=all&sort=newest&page=1&pageSize=15&layout=expanded&tagFilter=list&tags=mysql%20oracle%20oracle10g%20oracle11g%20sql%20sqlite%20sqlite3%20sql-server%20sql-server-2000%20sql-server-2005%20sql-server-2008%20sql-server-2008-r2%20sql-server-2012%20sql-server-2014%20tsql)